# Question on the operation of set inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B$ are two sets in a space $X$, can I define (in a way similar to the operation of implication in logic) $A\subseteq B$ as $(X\setminus A)\cup B$, where $\setminus$ denotes the operation of set difference?

Comment: $(X\setminus A)\cup B$ is not a statement while $A\subset B$ is. So no.

Comment: OK. What about $(X\setminus A)\cup B=X$ then?

Comment: Well, $(X\setminus A)\cup B = X\setminus(A\setminus B)$ so iff $(X\setminus A)\cup B=X$ then $A\setminus B=\emptyset$. So... @student

Comment: and $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ iff $A\subseteq B$, so $A\subset B$ iff $(X\setminus A)\cup B=X$ is true.